# Batch create a Folder in every subfolders and Move all the .jpg files in it

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

I made this batch file that makes a folder named Pictures and puts all the .jpg files in it.

```
@echo off
md Pictures
for %%i in ("*.jpg") do (
 move /Y "%%i" "Pictures" )
end
```

Is there anyway to make the script iterate through subdirectories as well? I want to run the batch file on a root directory and make it work for all subfolders.

Comment: Your question is currently unclear, please take another look at it, then edit it to make the required improvements. Once you move all of the files into the first subdirectory, there's none left to move into another! The simplest way to explain it is to provide before and after tree structures. You can use the `tree` command to create at least the before example: e.g. `tree X:\Directory /f`. Also there is no such command as `end`! If you're wanting to pick up all `.jpg` files in the current directory and all subdirectories, please take a look at the command help for the `for` command, `for /?`.

Comment: Type `for /?` and read about `/r` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the answer you've supplied, I would suggest you could do that like this, in a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For /D %%G In (*) Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%G" "%%G\Pictures" *.jpg /Mov >NUL 2>&1
```

As an alternative, because `For /D` may not pick up all of your directories, *(it ignores directories with the hidden and system attributes)*:

```batch-file
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /AD') Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%G" "%%G\Pictures" *.jpg /Mov >NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figured it out

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:d`) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  echo In Directory: %%a
  md Pictures
  for %%i in ("*.jpg") do (
  move /Y "%%i" "Pictures" )
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )
endlocal
```

It does the same thing but it works through subfolders. Took me sometime to figure it out. Anyway, hopefully it'll help others too.

Comment: It will not help others unless you follow the advice I provided in my comment under the question, because your task is only clear when the reader is capable of understanding your answer. Please edit your question, otherwise it will inevitably be closed for being unclear.

Comment: I changed the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: It is better, but TBF, the only way I understand what you're intending to do is by reading the answer above. I already explained that showing the before and after is a good way to explain it, _especially given that we have a large non natvie English speaking audience_.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code is much more elegant. If only I had it earlier! 
Thanks again.

Comment: You could have had it earlier, if your question was clearer! _And it's not just more elegant it is better_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Filepath"') do (
  md "%%~fa\Pictures"
  for %%b in ("*.jpg") do robocopy "%%~fb" "%%~fa\Pictures\" /mov
)
```

Comment: Wasif, as you can see by the OP's own answer, there was no intention of recursing the directories, simply the top level. It wasn't clear from the question, and despite informaing the OP of that multiple times, they did not provide the required clarification in a manner which would prevent others, like yourself, from posting answers which were not suitable for the intended task.

Comment: Ok Compo, I will remember your suggestion.